# Unable to execute groupby query using OData V4 query syntax in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to upgrade my web api to use OData V4 query syntax. After upgrading the dlls am able to issue `$filter` and `$select` queries for my web api.

But When I issue a request like `https://localhost:65000/api/Entitlement?$apply=groupby((Grade))`, getting below exception (am using NHibernate ORM)

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "MemberInitExpression",
  "exceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",
  "stackTrace": "   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessGroupBy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Process>b__0(Expression k)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessGroupBy.Process(GroupResultOperator resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModelVisitor, IntermediateHqlTree tree)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorProcessor`1.Process(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorMap.Process(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitResultOperator(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperatorBase.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitResultOperators(ObservableCollection`1 resultOperators, QueryModel queryModel)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at MatrixGroup.Bmx.Server.Filters.UnitOfWorkFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```